# Flink BroadcastProcessFunction vs CoProcessFunction

Tags: apache-flink

What are the differences between `BroadcastProcessFunction` and `CoProcessFunction` ?
As I understand it, you can do very similar things with their help
I mean to `.connect` streams, and in parallel process a message from both streams.
That is, using `CoProcessFunction` you can implement the functionality of Brodcast State.

when you should use broadcast state pattern and when you can use plain `.connect` + `CoProcessFunction` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the name really :) `BroadcastProcessFunction` allows You to broadcast one of the streams to all parallel operator instances, so If one of the streams contains generic data like a dictionary used for mapping then You can simply send it to all parallel operators using `broadcast`.

The `CoProcessFunction` will allow You to process two streams that were connected and partitioned across all parallel instances in some way, whether by using `keyBy` or `rebalance` or any other way.

So, basically the difference is that if you have two streams `s1` and `s2` and parallelism of 3. If You broadcast stream `s1` this means the all elements from `s1` will be passed to every single instance of `BroadcastProcessFunction`. If You however do something like `s1.connect(s2)`, then then only some subset of elements from s1 will be passed to each `CoProcessFunction`, depending on the partitioning.

Note that if You will use `parallelism` equal to 1 both of the functions will work more or less the same in terms of processing.